# getting data from static table in iOS5

Tags: uitableview, ios5, storyboard

**Question**:  Can I use table with static cells ( setup up in the storyboard ) as a datasource for another table?

Here's what I have ( a learning project ):

Storyboard
TabBarController with 4 table views:

TableViewOne - static cells ( entered in storyboard ) - 2 cells indicating what I selected ( desserts, appetizers, or both );

TableViewTwo - static cells ( entered in storyboard ) - appetizers;

TableViewThree - static cells ( entered in storyboard ) - desserts;

TableViewFour - dynamic - summary - all rows from either tableOne or TableTwo ( or both ) sorted in alphabetical order

Could I pull labels somehow from table 2 & 3 without having to load viewTwo or ViewThree.  That is the user selects appetizers and desserts in tableViewOne ( without looking  at TableViewTwo or TableViewThree ) and then switches to TableViewFour, where he expects to see all items from Table2 & Table3 listed in alphabetical order?

Thanks!